# Service to service api call authentication in spring cloud

Tags: oauth, microservices, spring-cloud

In spring cloud, if I need to call another micro-service, how should I do that?
If the API call needs to go thru API gateway, I need an authentication token. Do I need to do oauth2 first? What about I have to call other service frequently?

Comment: You can use Feign client and auth2 for secure endpoints. OAuth2 provided by OAuth2FeignRequestInterceptor from Spring Cloud OAuth2 library. Check this tutorial  https://piotrminkowski.wordpress.com/2017/12/01/part-2-microservices-security-with-oauth2/